# Torque direction and interpreting whether the object is speeding up or slowing down

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

I have understood that the convention is that counterclockwise Torque is taken as positive and clockwise torque is taken as negative, But my textbook says "If the net torque is positive, the object will commence rotating counterclockwise with increasing angular velocity.(If the object's initial rotation is clockwise, it will slow to a stop and then rotate counterclockwise with increasing angular speed)

I don't understand how it works

Comment: Exactly what don't you understand?

Comment: Like when Torque is negative, it is rotating clockwise why can't it increase in clockwise direction? why should it slow down and change direction?

Comment: Also how is increasing or decreasing torque works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torque results in angular acceleration, but says nothing about the speed or in which direction an object is actually rotating. If positive torque is applied, that simply means the object's angular velocity is becoming increasingly positive - it can go from a positive value to a larger positive value (speed up), from a negative value to a positive value (slow, stop, and reverse direction), or from a negative value to a smaller negative value (slow down).

When applying positive torque, if the object's angular velocity was already positive, the object spins faster in counterclockwise direction. If the object's angular velocity was zero, the object begins to spin in the counterclockwise direction. If the object's angular velocity was negative to start with, the mangnitude of object's angular velocity decreases as the object's rotation slows. Applying positive torque to an object with negative angular velocity means the object will slow down, stop, and then start spinning the other way.

Comment: So the speeding up or slowing down depends on the angular velocity right?

Comment: Thank you soo much @Nuclear Hoagie. I understood it.

Comment: @Shashaank. Yes. Positive torque makes the angular velocity move in the positive direction. If the angular velocity was negative, the magnitude of the angular velocity decreases, meaning that angular speed decreases (slowing down). If the angular velocity was positive, the magnitude of the angular velocity increases, resulting in faster rotation.